# NFA/DFA for $ L= \{a^n b^n a | n\ge0\}$

Tags: finite-automata

[image]I have made two DFA’s for $ L= \{a^n b^n a | n\ge0\}$.

First one has several states. The second one is accepting an empty string also.

Somebody please guide me the correct one.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FSM's can't count identical sequences, I don't think both of your answers would be correct. You can take a look [here, (pumping lemma)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) to prove why $L= \{a^nb^n | n \ge 0 \}$ is not regular, thus you can't write a FSM for it. Also a good [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309752/why-is-anbn-n-0-not-regular) here shows the proof. On the other hand it would be different if you are meaning $a^*b^*a$ which can be written as a FSM.

Comment: My question is : a^n b^n a, if we can draw a NFA i.e. also fine.

Comment: A NFA is also a FSM, so you I'm pretty sure you can't draw one

Comment: But you said that "On the other hand it would be different if you are meaning a∗b∗a which can be written as a FSM."

Comment: Yeah but $a^*b^*a$ is different than $a^nb^na$. If you want the first one it's easy we can write it.

Comment: Yes its a^*b^*a. I think we don't have a counting problem in this case because number of a's and b's are not equal.

Comment: Then you can make a 3 state NFA, first is self loop with "a", then a transition to the second state with also an "a", then in second state self loop with "b" and a transition with "a" to a final state. This should give you the NFA $a^*b^*a$